# How to get the multiplication result in each array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multiplication

This function makes every element multiply themselves and outputs 5040

```
function multiplyAll(arr) {
    var product = 1;

    for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
        for (var b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++) {
            product *= arr[a][b];
        }
    }
    return product;
}
multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);
```

I would like a function that displays the multiplication of the elements in each array (in this case, I would like the function to display [[2],[12],[210]]).

Any help, please

Comment: Could you clarify what the output should look like? It looks like you have it as an array of arrays, is that what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the desired effect without mutating the input:

```js
function multiplyAll (array) {
  return array.map(
    inner => [inner.reduce(
      (product, factor) => product * factor
    )]
  )
}

console.log(multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function multiplyAll(arr) {
    let products = [];

    for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
        let product = 1;
        for (var b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++) {
            product *= arr[a][b];
        }
        products.push([ product ]);
    }

    return products;
 }

 multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);
```

Just build up a new array and push the results to it.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following snippet which has minimal changes compared to your original program:

```js
function multiplyAll(arrs) {
    var product = 1;
    var result = [];

    for (var a = 0; a < arrs.length; a++) {
        for (var b = 0; b < arrs[a].length; b++) {
            product *= arrs[a][b];
        }
        result.push(product);
        product=1;
    }
    return result;
}
var product = multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```

Comment: Not quite the output specified in the question (compare your output with mine), but that may very well be a mistake on the asker's part.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I see what you are saying. If Louisff9 confirms that he wants the output to be not only correct but also in a specified format, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution out

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
 return arr.map((inner) => {
    let product = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < inner.length; i++) {
      product *= inner[i];
    }
    return [product];
  })
}
let product = multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```